# Connect client firedac to server and show data in dbgrid on client datasnap delphi

Tags: delphi, firedac, datasnap

How can I show data from a server in Delphi's `TDBGrid` on a client using Firedac and DataSnap?

Comment: Using the documentation, examples, and tutorials then if stuck asking more specific questions here would be more appropriate. As is this question is asking for somebody to write a tutorial for basic things covered elsewhere already.

Comment: Brian what documentation how can find ?

Answer (score 2):

I have on the Datasnap server a `TFDQuery` that is exposed through a public method

`function GetOrder(AId: Integer): TDataSet;`.

On the client, there is a `TFStoreProc` that binds the Datasnap server method (GetOrder) in the StoredProcName property.

Finally, a `TDatasource` is attached to the `TFDStoreProc` and the `TDatasource` is attached to the `DBGrid`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `TFDTable`. On the detail dataset, set the *Master Source* property to the master `TFDTable` and the *Master Fields* property to your master field in the master `TFDTable`. Also see [This Link](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/easily-build-master-detail-relationships-between-datasets-in-delphi-windows-apps/) on master - detail relationships.

Edit: I am terribly sorry I missed the DataSnap part. This is for FireDac.